# Combinations of unequal probabilities

Tags: probability

I want to find the probability that at least $6$ people will attend an event given that $n$ people are invited. However there's a different (independent) probability, $P_i$, for each person.
Is there some general formula for this, or do I need to enumerate all  possible combinations with $6$ or more people attending, calculate the probability for each one and add them together?

Comment: Well, it is still unattractive, but do all combinations of $5$ or fewer, and subtract the sum from $1$.

Answer (score 2):

For $0\le k\le5$, let $f(m,k)$ be the probability that exactly $k$ of the invitees $1$ through $m$ attend, and let $g(m)$ be the probability that $6$ or more of them attend. Omitting some obvious base cases, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
f(m,k)&=P_m f(m-1,k-1)+(1-P_m)f(m-1,k)\\
g(m)&=P_mf(m-1,5)+g(m-1)
\end{align}
$$

which yields a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) algorithm to compute $g(n)$ in $\Theta(n)$ time. In contrast, it takes at least $\binom n6=\Theta(n^6)$ time to enumerate all size-$6$ sets of attendees.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way.  You can see the formulas we know for equal probability attendance as being a function of the distributive law.  To make it simpler, consider two coins, one that comes up heads with probability $p$ and one that comes up heads with probability $q$.  The chance of at least one head is then $p+q-pq$.  If $p=q$ that can be simplified to $2p-p^2$, but only then.